# WCF - How to publish something to all clients from external source?

Tags: wcf, triggers

I have a client app (WPF) that connects to several services.
One of these services is a **Reminders Service**, that has a callback back to the client,
where it can send the client a 'Reminder' message, that the client can show on the screen.

But you may ask - when does this callback operation get fired from the service to the client ?

well, this happens when a new reminder row is added to the database (by a '**Command Service**').

I have 2 methods to implement this :

***METHOD A:***

When the 'Reminder Service' is instantiated, it will also start a 'Worker Thread' that will check the MS SQL database for a new reminder added to the database (either by using 'Sql Dependency' or by polling the database every couple of minutes \ hours).
Once a new reminder is found - the 'Worker Thread' should loop over all the WPF clients that are connected to it - and send them the 'Reminder Callback' message.

***METHOD B:***

Have the 'Command Service' (the actual service that adds the new reminder to the database) somehow trigger the 'Reminder Service' and tell it - 'I have just added a new reminder to the database. Go on and send the reminder to all of your connected clients'.

***METHOD C:***

This is really an elaboration of METHOD B - have the 'Command Service' connect to the 'Reminders Service' and send it a 'PublishReminder' message, that will in turn make the 'Reminders Service' go over all of it's clients and send them the reminder via a callback method.

.

**What is the best method ? Is there any better idea to do this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description, I would go with some variation of method C. For a sample implementation you could have a look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod), or in general for Publisher/Subscriber solutions, since it is a relatively common problem.

Comment: and what happens if I need a worker thread to scan the database - and for specific events - send a reminder to the clients ?
where does the worker thread fit in with the 'reminder service' ?

Comment: The worker thread could run potentially anywhere: in the reminder service itself or in a separate process or even machine, since it could make use of the same service operation the `Command Service` uses to notify the subscribers.